# Question on $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb{Q}(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$, where $\omega:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, galois-theory

We want to compute the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$, which is also denoted by $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb{Q}(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$, where $\omega:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\in \Bbb C$.

We know that $\omega$ is a root of the 3rd cyclotomic polynomial, which is $\Phi_3(X):=X^2+X+1\in \Bbb Z[X]$. Since it is monic, irreducible and with root this element, in fact it is the minimum polynomial of $\omega$ over $\Bbb Q$. Thus, 
$m_{(\omega,\Bbb Q)}(X)=X^2+X+1\in \Bbb Q[X]$ and the set 
$\mathcal{B:=\{1,\omega\}}\subseteq \Bbb{Q}(\omega) $ is a basis of the $\Bbb Q$-vector space $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$.

Let's take now an element $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb{Q}(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
\sigma : \Bbb{Q}(\omega) & \longrightarrow \Bbb{Q}(\omega),\\
x:=a+b\omega&\longmapsto\sigma(x)=\sigma (a+b\omega)=a+b \sigma( \omega)
\end{align*}
since $\sigma(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb Q$, by definition. Then, 
$\omega=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}} \implies \omega^3=1 \implies \sigma( \omega^3) = \sigma(1) \implies \sigma (\omega) ^3=1$ so
 we can see that 
$$\sigma(\omega)=e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{3}},\ k=0,1,2.$$
If $k=0\implies \sigma(\omega)=1$, then $\mathrm{Im}\sigma=\{\sigma(a+b):a+b\in \Bbb Q\}=\Bbb Q$, so in this case $\sigma$ is *not* surjective, and $\sigma \notin \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$.

If $k=1\implies \sigma(\omega)=\omega$, then $\sigma=\mathrm{Id}_{\Bbb Q(\omega)} \in \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$.

If $k=2\implies \sigma(\omega)=\omega^2=-\omega-1$, since $$\Phi(\omega)=0 \iff \omega^2+\omega+1=0 \iff \omega^2=-\omega-1.$$
We can show now that this is a homomorphism from $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ to itself.
Also,
$$\mathrm{Ker}\sigma=\{a+b\omega:\ \sigma(a+b\omega)=0\}.$$
So, $\sigma(a+b\omega)=0 \iff a+b(-\omega-1)= \iff (a-b)+(-b)\omega=0$ and since $1,\omega$ is a basis, we should have $a-b=0,-b=0\iff a=b=0$. So $\mathrm{Ker}\sigma=\{0\}$ and $\sigma$ is injective. Lastly, 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Im}\sigma \quad = & \quad \{\sigma(a+b\omega):\ a+b\omega\in \Bbb Q(\omega)\} \\ 
 \quad = & \quad  \{ \underbrace{(a-b)}_{\kappa}+\underbrace{(-b)}_{\lambda}\omega:a+b\omega\in \Bbb Q(\omega)  \}.\\
 \quad = & \quad \{ \kappa+\lambda\omega: \kappa,\lambda\in \Bbb Q\} \\
 \quad = & \quad \Bbb Q(\omega)
\end{align*}
and so $\sigma$ is surjective and name it $\psi$.

Finally, $\psi \in\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q)=\{\mathrm{Id}_{\Bbb Q(\omega)},\psi\}\cong (\Bbb Z_2,+)$.

*Remark.* Another way to work this would be to observe that $\omega=\frac{-1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$, so $\Bbb Q(\omega)=\Bbb Q(i\sqrt 3)$.

***Could you please verify if everything is correct and well written?***

Thank you

Comment: All looks good to me

Comment: you wrote $k=0$ twice, $k=1$ once, and $k=2$ no times !?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is this with the kernel (where I said that from the fact of the basis we obtain a=b=0) fine?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Thanks for your comment, I fixed the typo

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, how do we see that $\sigma(\omega)=\omega^{\frac{2k\pi i}{3}},\ k=0,1,2.$?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Check my update :)

Comment: I don't think you need all the case work. Since $X^2 + X + 1$ is irreducible, then $\sigma$ must send $\omega$ to a root of $X^2 + X + 1$. There are only two possibilities.

Comment: @Chris:  Did you mean  
$\sigma(\omega)=\omega^{ k }$ or 
$ \color{red}e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{3}},\ k=0,1,2.$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sometimes I am really clumsy. Yes, thank you.

Comment: @André3000 So the case $k=0$ is not needed you mean? Why that?

Comment: You know that $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$. Since $\sigma$ is a ring homomorphism, then $\sigma(\omega)^2 + \sigma(\omega) + 1 = 0$. $1$ does not satisfy this equation, so it can't be the case that $\sigma(\omega) = 1$. You basically made the same argument with the polynomial $X^3 - 1$, but it's more efficient to work with the minimal polynomial of the element $\omega$.

Comment: Got it. But even if without that we will find a contradiction. Right?

Comment: Sure, you showed that it implied that $\sigma$ is not surjective.